# How to get the frequency of NaN obsevations in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a pandas data frame with 83 columns and 4000 rows.  I intend to use the data for a logistic regression and therefore want to narrow down my columns to those that have the least amount of missing data.

To do this I was thinking of ranking them based on the frequency of NaN observations. I tried a few things like

```
econ_balance["BG.GSR.NFSV.GD.ZS"].describe()
econ_balance["BG.GSR.NFSV.GD.ZS"].value_counts
econ_balance["BG.GSR.NFSV.GD.ZS"]["NaN"]
econ_balance["BG.GSR.NFSV.GD.ZS"][NaN]
```

None of which seem to work. I always tried googling to see if this question has been answered before but no luck.

Thanks in advance for the help

Josh

Comment: df.isnull().sum()

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-the-column-in-panda-data-frame

Comment: Jeez I suddenly gained immediate duplicate close vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking just to count the `NaN` values:

```
In [2]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],'b':np.NaN, 'c':[np.NaN,1,2,3,np.NaN]})
df
Out[2]:
    a   b   c
0   0 NaN NaN
1   1 NaN   1
2 NaN NaN   2
3 NaN NaN   3
4 NaN NaN NaN
In [6]:

df.isnull().astype(int).sum()
Out[6]:
a    3
b    5
c    2
dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**
@CTZhu has pointed out the type casting is unnecessary:

```
In [7]:

df.isnull().sum()
Out[7]:
a    3
b    5
c    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: beat me to it, btw, I think you can skip the `astype(int)` part.