# pandas isnull sum with column headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which has multiple columns. I'd like to iterate through the columns, counting for each column how many null values there are and produce a new dataframe which displays the sum of `isnull` values alongside the column header names.

If I do:

```
for col in main_df:
    print(sum(pd.isnull(data[col])))
```

I get a list of the null count for each column:

```
0
1
100
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new dataframe which has the column header alongside the null count, e.g.

```
col1 | 0
col2 | 1
col3 | 100
```

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-the-column-in-panda-data-frame

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
     a    b  c
0  NaN  7.0  0
1  0.0  NaN  4
2  2.0  NaN  4
3  1.0  7.0  0
4  1.0  3.0  9
5  7.0  4.0  9
6  2.0  6.0  9
7  9.0  6.0  4
8  3.0  0.0  9
9  9.0  0.0  1

In [72]: pd.isnull(df).sum()
Out[72]:
a    1
b    2
c    0
dtype: int64
```

or:

```
In [76]: df.isnull().sum()
Out[76]:
a    1
b    2
c    0
dtype: int64
```

you can create a DF out of it:

```
In [78]: df.isnull().sum().to_frame('nulls')
Out[78]:
   nulls
a      1
b      2
c      0
```

Answer (score 2):

If the number of columns in your dataframe is greater than 10 you will end up with the middle columns being left out of the output. You can print every column using:

```
nulls = df.isnull().sum().to_frame()
for index, row in nulls.iterrows():
    print(index, row[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

for a certain dataset you could use to show you the missing values and the number

```
dataset.isnull().sum(axis = 0)
```