# Python Dataframe get null value counts

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the null values in a DataFrame. Though I reviewed the following post from Stackoverflow that describes the process to determine the null values, I am having a hard  time to do the same for my dataset.

[How to count the Nan values in the column in Panda Data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-the-column-in-panda-data-frame)

Working code:

```
import pandas as pd
a = ['america','britain','brazil','','china','jamaica'] #I deliberately introduce a NULL value
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
a.isnull()

#Output: 
False
1  False
2  False
3  False
4  False
5  False

a.isnull().sum()
#Output
#0    0
#dtype: int64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `''`, `None` and `NaN` to all count as `null`, you can use the `applymap` method on each value in the dataframe coerced to a `boolean` and then use `.sum` subsequently:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


a = ['america','britain','brazil',None,'', np.nan, 'china','jamaica'] #I deliberately introduce a NULL value
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
a.applymap(lambda x: not x or pd.isnull(x)).sum()

# 0    3
# dtype: int64
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The `''` in your list isn't a null value, it's an empty string. To get a null, use `None` instead. This is described in the [`pandas.isnull()` documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) that missing values are "NaN in numeric arrays, [or] None/NaN in object arrays".

```
import pandas as pd
a = ['america','britain','brazil',None,'china','jamaica']
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
a.isnull()

       0
0  False
1  False
2  False
3   True
4  False
5  False
```

You can see the difference by printing the two dataframes. In the first case, the dataframe looks like:

```
pd.DataFrame(['america','britain','brazil',None,'china','jamaica'])

         0
0  america
1  britain
2   brazil
3         
4    china
5  jamaica
```

Notice that the value at index 3 is an empty string.

In the second case, you get:

```
pd.DataFrame(['america','britain','brazil',None,'china','jamaica'])

         0
0  america
1  britain
2   brazil
3     None
4    china
5  jamaica
```

Comment: "Unlike standard Python, an empty string in pandas isn't considered a null value." I don't think this is correct. The empty string is still a string!

Comment: @AndyHayden That line was poor wording on my part. I was trying to point out the difference between null values and things that test as False.

Answer (score 0):

The other posts addressed that `''` is not a null value and therefore isn't counted as such with the `isnull` method...

...However, `''` does evaluate to `False` when interpreted as a `bool`.

```
a.astype(bool)

       0
0   True
1   True
2   True
3  False
4   True
5   True
```

This might be useful if you have `''` in your dataframe and want to process it this way.