# Return Column(s) if they Have a certain Percentage of NaN Values (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, nan

#### Looking to return only the columns that have at least 25% NaN values *as a new df*

> I'm thinking either a ***conditional statement** using **.loc**, **.isnull**, or **count***, but I'm not certain what the most efficient method is. Appreciate any and all assistance.

DF:

```
df1:
(axis 1 = A,B,C = series)

    A    B    C
1   1    2    1
2   NaN  NaN  3
3   4    NaN  1
4   2    NaN  4
```

Thinking:

```
df.loc[df['series'] == nan >= 25% ]
```

Or something like:

```
if count(nan) for column(x) in 'series' is >= (.25 * (count(x)))
    return loc[x]
```

Return **New Dataframe**:

```
df2:

    A    B    
1   1    2    
2   NaN  NaN  
3   4    NaN  
4   2    NaN
```

Returns A and B because each of those have at least 25% of their column entries as NaN (missing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find out the percentage of missing values in each column in the given dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070985/find-out-the-percentage-of-missing-values-in-each-column-in-the-given-dataset)

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately no. That is helpful for identifying the percentages of each column, but in terms of restructuring the df based on a given percentage threshold, it seems to be lacking. My goal is to skip the process of identifying missing values per column and jump straight to a new df that only includes the columns following the rules of the threshold.

Comment: @Alex Can’t you just use `dropna()`?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile To my understanding, `dropna()` would drop the NaNs, would it not? I want to drop the columns that don't have at least 25% NaN. So maybe I could use it in a conditional? But I do not know how I would apply that.

Comment: @Alex Looking at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), you could have it drop rows where the number of NA values (`thresh` parameter) is greater than 25% of the number of columns you have.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile That definitely works for dropping the NA's, which was not my initial intention but is a shortcut to my end goal. That thresh parameter is what I'm struggling with now: `df.dropna(axis= 1, thresh= .75 * count(), inplace = True)`

Comment: @Alex I had misread, my bad. Take a look at this, it seems perfect: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/16801.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the responses from https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/12645.

```py
na_count_mask = df.isna().sum(axis=0) >= (col_count // 4)

res_df = df.loc[na_count_mask]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @Alex I could have maybe split that one line, to make it easier to read. All good though, it’s clear?

Comment: Very! Thanks again