# Counting in pandas and assigning output to a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to python and pandas so forgive me if this is a somewhat basic question. I am reading in some data from a csv file, I want to do a tally from column 'gender' of 'M', 'F' and NaN. The code below outputs this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.read_csv("....csv")
    count = pd.value_counts(df['gender'],dropna=False)
```

This outputs:

```
    M      22
    F       3
    NaN     1
```

However, I don't want to just see these as a tally, I want the values to be assigned to variables. I.e. have

```
    male = pd.value_counts(df['gender'],'M',dropna=False)
```

or something similar, giving male = 22 (and the same for female and Nan), however I can't find an obvious way to do this using pandas.
Any advice? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: And how do I call count? It is not part of pandas as far as I can see and saying "name 'count' is not defined" if I don't include a library?

Comment: well... you get your counts like `count = df['gender'].value_counts(dropna=False)`... then you get a series whose index is the key and the value is the count... you can then access individual values by `male = count['M']` for instance...

Comment: So what you already had but pointing out you can use `[]` syntax to access the values...

Comment: Ah got it! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to list the NaN values in the same way?
I get:
File "/usr...python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3132, in get_value
    raise e1
KeyError: 'NaN'

error when I try to do the same for count['NaN'] or count [' ']?

Comment: access it using `np.nan`, eg: `count[np.nan]`...

Comment: TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [nan] of <type 'float'>

You seen this one before?

Comment: Umm... is `type(count)` a `pandas.core.series.Series` ?

Comment: Yes (IGNORE: need 12 more characters to send)

Comment: Hmm having googled a bit more (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe) your suggestion seems to match suggestions elsewhere, so I don't quite know

Comment: what pandas version are you using?

Comment: pandas 0.23.4 so I think I'm up to date?

Comment: I also have a related question if you have time:
Say instead of just M, F, nan we had potentially hundreds of options (e.g. favourite food) and I wanted to pull out the 10 most common foods: the number of times that food is chosen and the name of the food, is that possible using pandas or are their more suitable tools out there?

Comment: `value_counts` returns the series in descending order of frequency... so you can just do `count.head(10)` to get the top 10...

Answer (score 1):

In this example we take the count of the `gender` series filtered by `== "male"`

```
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': [random.choice(['male', 'female']) for x in range(100)]})
count_men = df[df["gender"] == "male"].count()
count_men
```

And if you just want the integer you can take it as the zeroth value:

```
count_men = df[df["gender"] == "male"].count()[0]
```