# TypeError unhashable type: 'set' when you extract and select nan in dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, typeerror, nan, missing-data

I'm trying to select nan values in panda dataframe by picking them in columns or rows and extract them and save in csv file but I faced TypeError
unhashable type: 'set' which I'm wondering how can I fix it get result.

As it can be seen in following scripts I've selected them by using `isnull()`function after convert inf values to nan for counting but in the enc I couldn't store nan values in my target column which is `'C'` in csv file due to  `TypeError unhashable type: 'set'`. Following is my scripts:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#extract the parameters and put them in lists based on id_set
df = pd.read_csv('D:\m22.TXT', header=None)
id_set = df[df.index % 4 == 0].astype('int').values
a = df[df.index % 4 == 1].values
b = df[df.index % 4 == 2].values
c = df[df.index % 4 == 3].values
data = {'A': a[:,0], 'B': b[:,0], 'C': c[:,0] }
main_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','C'], index = id_set[:,0])
#Mark nan and inf by isnu() function
nan = np.array(main_data.isnull())
inf = np.array(main_data.isnull())
#Make sure to change inf values into nan
main_data = main_data.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
c = main_data.isnull().sum()
print(c)
percent_missing = main_data.isnull().sum() * 100 / len(main_data)
print(percent_missing)
#calculate nan values in percentage in desired column
m = len(main_data) - main_data['A'].count()
print(m)
#Monitor the data
print(main_data)
print (main_data.isnull())
print (main_data.isnull().any(axis=1))
#Select columns has nan(s)
print(main_data[main_data['C'].isnull()])
#Select rows has nan(s) based on id_set
nan_data = main_data[main_data.isnull().any(axis = {'C'})]
print (nan_data)
#write selected part in csv file by id_set
nan_data.to_csv('nan_data.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

my data frame looks like following:

```
             A          B            C
0       -56.343656        nan  -418.540483
10      -87.577880 -16.061497          inf
20             nan -15.337254          inf
30      -83.724143 -18.061570  -531.053979
40      -67.462841        nan  -431.924830
50      -63.377158 -28.260790          inf
60             nan -22.996095          nan
70      -38.386860 -35.921773  -534.576631
```

desired output for `'C'` following:

```
              'C'
10          inf/nan
20          inf/nan
50          inf/nan
60            nan
```

Here below is my dataset sample: [dataset sample DL link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=21007523126049722925)

Note: `id_set` values is written not completely eg. `000` shown as `0` 
Hopefully someone has a good hint to fix it.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. Otherwise we have to pore through your code trying to work out which line threw the exception, and that is nearly always a stimulus to go and look at the next question instead.

Comment: since missing data appear in middle of dataset it's difficult for me to find and post entire stack trace, I hope you understand me. but I'll upload the text file and hopefully will work out!

Comment: Unhashable means an immutable data type is expected but a mutable one was found (for example having a set as a dictionary key). So look for where that's happening and you'll solve your problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I *don't* understand. There can't be more than a couple of dozen lines between `Traceback (most recent call last):` and `TypeError unhashable type: 'set'`. Those are the lines we want to see. Without them it is very hard to tell what the problem is. You found the error message easily enough. If you want help, then help us to help you.

Comment: @BoarGules Absolutely you're right that's why I uploaded the sample of dataset. I hope you could follow me by that.

Comment: @timkofu yes I saw in similar posts but it's not my case as far as I know!

Comment: That link gives me an error 404. I'm afraid I have better things to do than repeatedly ask you to pick the stack trace out of your output and post it.

Comment: @BoarGules sorry for inconvenience I just re-uploaded again in another place. Idk why it's expired as soon as left the link here !!! probably there's problem of https://uploadfiles.io/ I already tried 2 times before leaving this link. this one works dear.

Comment: @BoarGules surely you can access to sample dear. Sorry because of immediate expiration of initial link. for sure you can follow my issue if you're interested. Waiting for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's exactly your goal, but in case you want to output all rows in which at least one entry is either nan or inf you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(50*np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=np.arange(0, 80, 10).astype(int))
df.loc[0, 'A'] = np.nan
df.loc[10, 'C'] = np.inf
df.loc[20, 'B'] = np.nan
df.loc[20, 'C'] = np.inf
df.loc[50, 'C'] = np.inf
df.loc[60, 'C'] = np.nan

df[np.isinf(df)] = np.nan    # convert inf to nan

df_nan = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]   # extract sub data frame

df_nan.to_csv('nan_data.csv', header=None, index=None)   # export
```

The input data frame (after converting inf to nan) looks like:

[image: Input, once inf are converted to nan]

The output looks like:

[image]

To output index label and 'NaN' in csv file you can use:

```
df_nan.to_csv('nan_data.csv', na_rep='NaN')
```

This will output:

[image]

If you only want column 'C' you can use:

```
df_nan['C'].to_csv('nan_dataC.csv', na_rep='NaN')
```

If you'd like to have leading zeros, you can do the following:

```
new_index = [str(x).zfill(3) for x in df_nan.index]
df_nan.index = new_index
```

Comment: it would be great if you edit your answer via changing these parameters Sxy to B and Sx-Sy to A and Temperature to C to reformulate it generally since I've edited them.

Comment: I believe that It doesn't make a sense to that by marking nan and inf values manually ! I was wondering if we can select missing values and store it in csv file by `id_set` which can helps to find location of missing values ! I have lots of missing values in my dataset!

Comment: Hi Mario, marking by hand was just to reproduce a data frame with a similar structure from what you posted. I wrote it before the link was available. Just an example. Can't open the link. If you print the first 6 lines from your data frame, happy to help.

Comment: Hi man! I see , Do you have another suggestion to fulfill this task ?

Comment: Can you print the first few lines of the data frame? Also, you want to extract all the lines where at least one value is either inf or nan?

Comment: As above-mentioned I already did and left in question. Yes man,unfortunately I've got lots of inf and nan in `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` and I want to exclude them in csv file by id_set which can help me out where they happen so that I can figure it out how can try impute them by right value in further steps

Comment: From the example above that you posted, can you print out the first 2 lines of the output you'd like to see?

Comment: I updated in end of question, dear, plz check it out.

Comment: you mean `df_nan.to_csv(na_rep='NaN')` but dear I need to see  all includes `id_set` which shows `0` , `10` , `20`, `50`, `60` in csv file !

Comment: It doesn't write `id_set` :  `0` , `10` , `20`, `50`, `60` which is important to have for me in csv file! when you print `df_nan` you can see `id_set` but in there's no track of it in csv file!

Comment: Hi Mario. I took the output from your code, assuming that's what you wanted. Use: df_nan.to_csv('nan_data.csv', na_rep='NaN') to output the indices and have a 'NaN' for either inf or nan.

Comment: Thanks for reply @deckard that's right as I mentioned when you add this `na_rep='NaN'` you can catch them and even you can just print index which I was interested by 
`for i in range(len(df_nan)):
    print (df_nan.index[i])`  but man one further question is ther any elegant way to count these nan in each cycle and print them as well?

Comment: oh yeah base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe)  you can count them easily 
print(df_nan.isna().sum())
print(df_nan.isnull().sum().sum())

Comment: Man do you have any idea why in `id_set` which is our `index` exists in dataset in text file like `000`, `010` , `020`, `050` , `060` but when we print them they'd print out like this form `0` , `10` , `20` , `50 , `60` ? can we fix it?

Comment: Hi Mario, I posted a solution: use a new index that has strings instead of numbers: new_index = [str(x).zfill(3) for x in df_nan.index]. You can control the number of leading zeros by changing the '3' in str(x).zfill(3).

Comment: Merci man , It worked out properly! Kindly would you check out my another question post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166009/is-it-possible-to-get-plot-from-panda-dataframe-includes-missing-data-by-heatmap) which is related to data frame. I'd like to visualise a large pandas-dataframe includes 3 columns `columns=['A','B','C']` via heatmaps in-one-window but due to a for-loop which includes data frame I couldn't get proper output due to in each cycle it prints plot each of ['A','B','C'] 3 times in different intervals eg. it prints `'A'` under the name of `'B'`and `'C'` and so on!

Comment: man would u do me a favor and have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489201/how-can-make-a-dataset-of-elements-of-matrices-in-dataframe) You might have an idea?