# Python: How to replace missing values column wise by median

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1.45, 2.33, np.nan], 'C': [4, 5, 6], 'D': [4.55, 7.36, np.nan]})
```

I want to replace the missing values i.e. `np.nan` in generic way. For this I have created a function as follows

```
def treat_mis_value_nu(df):
    df_nu = df.select_dtypes(include=['number'])
    lst_null_col = df_nu.columns[df_nu.isnull().any()].tolist()
        if len(lst_null_col)>0:
            for i in lst_null_col:
                if df_nu[i].isnull().sum()/len(df_nu[i])>0.10:
                    df_final_nu = df_nu.drop([i],axis=1)
                else:
                    df_final_nu = df_nu[i].fillna(df_nu[i].median(),inplace=True)
    return df_final_nu
```

When I apply this function as follows

```
df_final = treat_mis_value_nu(df)
```

I am getting a dataframe as follows

```
    A    B  C
 0  1  1.0  4
 1  2  2.0  5
 2  3  NaN  6
```

So it has actually removed column `D` correctly, but failed to remove column `B`.
I know in past there have been discussion on this topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe)). Still I might be missing something?

Comment: Can you put a statement, explaining what you want in your `generic` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3,5,7], 'B': [1.45, 2.33, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'C': [4, 5, 6,8,7], 'D': [4.55, 7.36, np.nan,9,10],
                   'E':list('abcde')}) 
print (df)
   A     B  C      D  E
0  1  1.45  4   4.55  a
1  2  2.33  5   7.36  b
2  3   NaN  6    NaN  c
3  5   NaN  8   9.00  d
4  7   NaN  7  10.00  e

def treat_mis_value_nu(df):
    #get only numeric columns to dataframe
    df_nu = df.select_dtypes(include=['number'])
    #get only columns with NaNs
    df_nu = df_nu.loc[:, df_nu.isnull().any()]
    #get columns for remove with mean instead sum/len, it is same
    cols_to_drop = df_nu.columns[df_nu.isnull().mean() <= 0.30]
    #replace missing values of original columns and remove above thresh    
    return df.fillna(df_nu.median()).drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1)

print (treat_mis_value_nu(df))
   A  C      D  E
0  1  4   4.55  a
1  2  5   7.36  b
2  3  6   8.18  c
3  5  8   9.00  d
4  7  7  10.00  e
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael: This is good. Just another related query; If a column in the above example contains `string` then I want to replace `nan` as `blank`. I have changed the last line of the function as `return df.fillna('blank').drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1)`. But this is not working. I.e. I am still getting `nan` in the `df`. Please do let me know how to tackle this.

Comment: @pythondumb - hmm, so not working `return df.fillna(df_nu.median()).drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1).fillna('blank')` ? Maybe need `return df.fillna(df_nu.median()).drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1).replace('NaN', 'blank')`

Comment: Let me check. Besides I can't do `df.apply(lambda x:f(x))` operation. Here `f(x)` is nothing but a simple regex as `re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', text)`. Do I need to convert the particular column (like in your example `E` col) to `astype(str)`?

Comment: @pythondumb - not sure if underatand, can you show it with change data?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the sklearn [Imputer transformer](http://lijiancheng0614.github.io/scikit-learn/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html). I don't think it it can drop columns but it can definetly fill them in a 'generic way' - for example, filling in missing values with the median of the relevant column.

You could use it as such:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer = Imputer(strategy='median')

num_df = df.values
names = df.columns.values

df_final = pd.DataFrame(imputer.transform(num_df), columns=names)
```

If you have additional transformations you would like to make you could consider making a transformation [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) or could even make your own transformers to do bespoke tasks.