# How to redistribude the the value equaly between NaN values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
                'B'         'C'
1/1/2017    'A' 
            BTC NaN       0.367392
            ETH NaN       0.367392
            XRP 0.164735  0.164735
            LTC 0.100481  0.100481
1/2/2017    BTC NaN       0.315265
            XRP NaN       0.315265
            ETH NaN       0.315265
            LTC 0.054204  0.054204
```

I want to redistribute (1 - df['B'].groupby(level=0).sum()) equally between NaN values.
Column 'C' is an example of an expected output.

Comment: What is formula? I get a bit different output.

Comment: @jezrael I apologize, I gave a wrong example of the formula. I need (1 - df['B'].groupby(level=0).sum())
Thank you. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by first level of `MultiIndex` with `sum`, for second count number of NaNs by check missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with `sum`, divide and replace missing values:

```
print (df)
                     C         D
A        B                      
1/1/2017 BTC       NaN  0.367392
         ETH       NaN  0.367392
         XRP  0.164735  0.164735
         LTC  0.100481  0.100481
1/2/2017 BTC       NaN  0.315265
         XRP       NaN  0.315265
         ETH       NaN  0.315265
         LTC  0.054204  0.054204

sum1 = 1 - df['C'].groupby(level=0).transform('sum')
len1 = df['C'].isna().groupby(level=0).transform('sum')

df['E'] = df['C'].fillna(sum1 / len1)
print (df)
                     C         D         E
A        B                                
1/1/2017 BTC       NaN  0.367392  0.367392
         ETH       NaN  0.367392  0.367392
         XRP  0.164735  0.164735  0.164735
         LTC  0.100481  0.100481  0.100481
1/2/2017 BTC       NaN  0.315265  0.315265
         XRP       NaN  0.315265  0.315265
         ETH       NaN  0.315265  0.315265
         LTC  0.054204  0.054204  0.054204
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You can get more info on how to count non-nan values from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe) and on`isnull()`from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530232/how-to-check-if-any-value-is-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

Regardless of the answer you use, always catch the case where a column has no NaN value. In this case both answers will cause a division by zero error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
test = [np.NAN,np.NAN,np.NAN,np.NAN,0.123128,0.1238123]
df = pd.DataFrame({"B":test})
df["C"] = df["B"].copy()
df["C"][df["C"].isnull()] = (1-df["B"].dropna().sum())/(len(df["B"]) - df["B"].count())
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          B         C
0       NaN  0.188265
1       NaN  0.188265
2       NaN  0.188265
3       NaN  0.188265
4  0.123128  0.123128
5  0.123812  0.123812
```