# How to show counts of null string-like column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The `dataframe.describe()` has the following columns for string like columns:

```
count unique top freq first last
```

[image]

While these are certainly useful it is also v important to understand if there were null values in any given columns and how many.

While I could resort to writing custom function to find this it would be a significant additional overhead.   Note that there is a *related* question but that focuses on *numeric* columns and is thus not directly applicable:  [How to count the NaN values in a column in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe).  So is there another helper function that can provide that additional information?

Comment: `dataframe.isna().sum()`?

Comment: what about `df.describe(include="all")`? The count is the count of non-nulls. So if you know the length, you know how many are null. For example: `df.shape[0] - df.describe(include="all").loc["count", :]`

Comment: Try `df.info()` as well.

Comment: @VivekSolanki  Please make that an answer . Oh hold on .. the `info()` does _display_ the null counts needed but my need is to capture the counts in a Series or DataFrame not just have it blindly dumped to stdout. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: What do you mean by capture the counts in a series or df? please elaborate

Comment: `info()` prints to console . that is not helpful when the goal is to store the summary stats in an in memory data structure

Comment: @QuangHoang  Yes!  Please make that an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick glance of number of `nan` in each columns:

```
dataframe.isna().sum()
```

Comment: actually this is not just a "quick glance" since a fully structured dataframe is returned. I need that for in-memory data structure.  I will probably join this result to the dataframe returned by `pd.describe()` to give a complete one-place summary

Comment: I used your result in a fully realized enhanced `describe()` containing the `Nulls` column: see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can try: `dataframe.info()`

As mentioned [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html), `df.info()`gives you information about a DataFrame including the index dtype and column dtypes, non-null values and memory usage.

Based on your requirement to store the info, you can try following:

```
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
s = buffer.getvalue()
with open("df_info.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:  
     f.write(s)
```

Source: [df.info() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html)

Comment: `info()` prints to console . While this approach is helpful for casual evaluation it  is less so  when the goal is to store the summary stats in an in memory data structure. I will upvote since it is useful for the former use case but I am still looking for an approach to capture the na counts in a data structure. It may be that combining `df.describe()` with `df.counts()` will do the trick: i am working on that now. Oh nmd  @QuangHoang has a little bit better answer

Comment: Your updated answer just allows storing the result as a string blob. It is not a data structure.

Comment: Agree. I will leave it as it is if someone in future wants to store it as a string blob.

Answer (score 1):

## Include the Nulls Counts with describe()

The following provides the full realization of my original intent to add the `nulls` column to the information provided by `dataframe.describe()`.  Credit to @QuangHoang for mentioning the `dataframe.isna().sum()` that forms part of this answer.

Notice that we have to transpose the output from `describe()`. The `Nulls` is then pre-pended to the transposed `describe()` output and the column is renamed to `Nulls` via `set_axis`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['a','b','c'], 'c': [99.5,11.2, 433.1],
   'd':[123,'abc',None]})
desc = df.describe()  # Returns a DataFrame with stats in the row index
combo = pd.concat([df.isna().sum(),desc.T],axis=1)
          .set_axis(['Nulls']+list(desc.index),axis=1,inplace=False)
```

[image]