# Counting NaN values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I try to analyse wind speed data from a lidar, creating a dataframe in which the columns are the investigated heights and the row is the number of NaNs at that elevation. My script creates the dataframe and names the columns as it required but it doesn't write the number of NaNs in the corresponding cells. Any idea what the problem might be?

```
df=pd.read_csv(fileApath,delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
heights = ['123','98','68','65','57','48','39','38','29','18','10']
nanvalues_speed=pd.DataFrame()
for i in heights:
    nanvalues_speed[i+'m']=pd.notnull(df['Horizontal Wind Speed (m/s) at '+i+'m']).sum()
```

Comment: I think this would help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Can you add some data sample, 3-4 rows, 2-3 columns with expected output?

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `pd.isna()` instead of `pd.notnull()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is pandas.DataFrame.isna()
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,np.nan ,5], 
                   'b': ['a',np.nan ,'c','d','e']})

df.isna().sum()
```

The pandas.DataFrame.isna() funtion returns a boolean same-sized object indicating if the values in the DataFrame are NA.

Comment: thanks. isna and sum don't work if they are in the same line but they are ok if separated