# how to find which rows have more than certain columns with values (e.g. 20 columns) in Panda?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the e.g. [100,30] data frame, I would like to find which rows have more than 20 columns with values?
Well all rows have 30 columns, but some of them have NaN values, therefore I set a limit of 20 columns and I wanna find which rows have values for the column after col.iloc = 20

For example, even though at row number 05 we have more Nan value, due to distribution I would like to find which rows have more than 3 columns either with the value of X or Nan (in the table below I want to find the index of rows number 1, 3, 4 and 7. because they have value for the columns after index.column=3, and my question is among the large data set how should I find them).

| ID | Col.01 | Col.02 | Col.03 | Col.04 | Col.05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | X | X | X | X | X |
| 02 | X | X | X | Nan | Nan |
| 03 | X | X | X | X | X |
| 04 | X | X | X | X | Nan |
| 05 | X | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 06 | X | X | X | Nan | Nan |
| 07 | X | X | X | X | Nan |

My expected result:

I find out that the ID of the row: 1,3,4,7 are the rows have values in column>3, so I can delete them after that

| ID | Col.01 | Col.02 | Col.03 | Col.04 | Col.05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02 | X | X | X | Nan | Nan |
| 05 | X | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 06 | X | X | X | Nan | Nan |

but in large dataframe It would not that easy

Comment: "*which rows have more than 3 columns either with the value of X or Nan*": what do you mean? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df.column.isna().sum()
```

to find the number of NaN values in a column. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266362/how-to-count-the-nan-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: No, maybe I wrote not explicitly, I wanna find which rows have more than 3 columns either with value X or NaN (NaN is not an issue here)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
out = df[df.iloc[:, 4:].isna().all(axis=1)]
print(out)

# Output
   ID Col.01 Col.02 Col.03 Col.04 Col.05
1  02      X      X      X    NaN    NaN
4  05      X    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
5  06      X      X      X    NaN    NaN
```

If your columns have names, you can use `df.loc[:, 'Col.04':]` instead of `df.iloc[:, 4:]`.

Comment: I meant any values, NaN value is not an issue here, imagine the problem is out of 100 rows and 30 columns I want to remove some rows which have values in the index.column >20. for example in above table I want to remove the rows of 1, 3, 4, 7. Therefore first I have to find the index of rows

Comment: @MohsenShahvar. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?